# PRAW: How to get a Reddit user total number of submissions when it is greater than 1000?

Tags: python, python-3.x, reddit, praw

I am trying to get a Reddit user total number of submissions, but the Reddit API is limited to showing only 1000 posts.

Because of this, the following code will not work for users that have more than a thousand submissions:

```
import praw

reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id='CLIENT_ID',
                     client_secret='SECRET_KEY',
                     user_agent='USER_AGENT',
                     username='USERNAME',
                     password='PASSWORD')

counter = 0
submissions = reddit.redditor('REDDIT_USERNAME').submissions.new(limit=None)

for submission in submissions:
    counter += 1

print(counter)
```

Likewise, I have tried simply doing `print(len(submissions))`, but I get the following:

`TypeError: object of type 'ListingGenerator' has no len()`

Is there any way to get a user total number of submissions if he/she has more than a 1000 posts?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

## This is not possible with PRAW or any other Reddit API client.

Reddit's API limits listings to about 1000 items. You cannot use the Reddit API to get more items than that, using PRAW or any other Reddit API Wrapper.

However, third party services like [PushShift](https://pushshift.io) have Reddit data and APIs to get more than 1000 posts by a user, with the caveat that the items must be public.

Answer (score 1):

There's one of a few ways, and some are more perfect than others.

You can visit each sort (so like sort by hot, new, top) over all of the time periods (day, week, month, year, all). Depending on the activity of the user, this may be enough. You can use the Pushshift API to get public submissions.

I explain in a [comment I made on the redditdev subreddit](https://old.reddit.com/r/redditdev/comments/9vmpqt/hello_is_there_a_limit_to_how_far_back_in_a_subs/e9deohf/):

> yes. generally speaking you can get the last 1000 items in a listing
>   (/r/all and /r/popular listings are higher), regardless of how long
>   ago it is.
>
> to get more than 1000 items:
>
> [...]
>
> if this is a public subreddit, consider also using pushshift.io